# Rotate single page of document

Tags: java, itext

How do I rotate the second page of my PdF when I'm using iText.

The first and other pages I would like to stay in the same orientation.

I know of ...

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 50, 50, 50, 50);
```

But that will rotate everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=232 :

```java
/*
 * This class is part of the book "iText in Action - 2nd Edition"
 * written by Bruno Lowagie (ISBN: 9781935182610)
 * For more info, go to: http://itextpdf.com/examples/
 * This example only works with the AGPL version of iText.
 */

package part4.chapter13;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import part1.chapter03.MovieTemplates;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNumber;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

public class RotatePages {

    /** The resulting PDF. */
    public static final String RESULT
        = "results/part4/chapter13/timetable_rotated.pdf";

    /**
     * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     * @param src the original PDF
     * @param dest the resulting PDF
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     */
    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MovieTemplates.RESULT);
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        int rot;
        PdfDictionary pageDict;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            rot = reader.getPageRotation(i);
            pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
            pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rot + 90));
        }
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method creating the PDF.
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new MovieTemplates().createPdf(MovieTemplates.RESULT);
        new RotatePages().manipulatePdf(MovieTemplates.RESULT, RESULT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can  use `document.setPageSize()` before `document.addNew();`.

For example:

```
Document document = new Document();
....
document.setPageSize(PageSie.A4);
document.newPage();
......

document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
document.newPage();
```

It worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I rotate the orientation:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(out);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.LETTER.rotate());
```

Comment: Isn't this what the op said *he knew of* but which in contrast to what he wanted *will rotate everything* instead of merely a given page?